# Send email after approval task is complete

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Got a list about new suppliers. There is one field where it has two options yes or no. If selection is no then confirmation process will be launched.

After that supervisor either approves or rejects it. How could I send an email based on those two buttons status?

I did If field = rejected then do nothing else send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this SPD 2010 or 2013? How are you running the approval task?

In SP2013 workflows you can use the "Start a Task Process" activity to run an approval task on the current list item (i.e. create a task form and assign it to a specific approver) and save the outcome to a variable. By default, this activity will cause the workflow to pause until an outcome is reached; so you can react to the outcome by placing an `If... else` block immediately after the task process.

[image: Start a Task Process configuration]

Then you would configure the `If..Else` block like so:

If `Outcome` is *Rejected*
And `YesOrNoField` is *No*

Send Notification to *Recipient*

[image]

You can also do this with SPD 2010 workflows but it is a little less straightforward.

Comment: It is SP2013. I will check it today

Comment: Ok so I just found out that we don't have SP2013 engine. We use 2010. Aprroval task is runned by check if Contract signed? = Yes or No. If no then start confirmation process... and it does what it needs to do